# How to use Cursor adapter which can view Different Cursor Types

Tags: java, android

I need to implement a `cursorAdapter` that can handle and view Different type of cursor one for movie trailer and the other for movie reviews, so I have the main Activity where init Cursor Loader returns 2 Cursor (`trailerCursor` and `ReviewCursor`) and I used for that in `MainActivity`. What happening now is that after each finish of loader Reviews Data overwrite Trailers.

```
 public static int Current_type=-1;

 case MOVIE_TRAILER_LOADER:{
                if(data.moveToFirst()){
                Current_type=0;
                movieAdapter.swapCursor(data);
                }
                break;
            }
  case MOVIE_REVIEW:{
                if(data.moveToFirst()){
                    Current_type=1;
                    movieAdapter.swapCursor(data);
                }
                break;
            }   



public class movie_detailsAdapter extends CursorAdapter{


private final static int TYPES_COUNT=2;

private final static int TRAILER_TYPE=0;
private final static int REVIEW_TYPE=1;



public static class Review_ViewHolder{
    public final TextView review_author;
    public final TextView review_content;

    public Review_ViewHolder(View view){
        review_author=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.review_author);
        review_content=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.review_content);
    }
}

public static class TRAILER_ViewHolder{
    public final TextView Trailer_name;

    public TRAILER_ViewHolder(View view){
        Trailer_name=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.trailer_name);
    }
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return TYPES_COUNT;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return   (Movie_Fragment.Current_type==0)?TRAILER_TYPE:REVIEW_TYPE;
}

public movie_detailsAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    //why

    int ViewType=getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition());
    int layid=-1;

    switch (ViewType){
        case TRAILER_TYPE:{
            layid=R.layout.trailer_item;
        break;
        }
        case REVIEW_TYPE:{
            layid=R.layout.review_item;
            break;
        }
    }


    View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layid,viewGroup,false);

    if(ViewType==TRAILER_TYPE){
        TRAILER_ViewHolder tHolder=new TRAILER_ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(tHolder);
    }

    if(ViewType==REVIEW_TYPE){
        Review_ViewHolder rHolder=new Review_ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(rHolder);
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    int ViewType=getItemViewType(cursor.getPosition());
    if(ViewType==TRAILER_TYPE) {
        TRAILER_ViewHolder mHolder=(TRAILER_ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        mHolder.Trailer_name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbContract.MOVIE_VIDEOS.OWM_COLUMN_TRAILER_NAME)));
    }

    else if((ViewType==REVIEW_TYPE)){

        Log.i("sadsadsadsadsa",cursor.getString(2));

        Review_ViewHolder mHolder=(Review_ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        mHolder.review_author.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbContract.MOVIES_REVIEWS_TABLE.OWM_COLUMN_REVIEW_CONTENT)));
    }

}
```